# Reading elements into a matrix from binary file to separate processors in MPI causes segmentation faults

Tags: c, matrix, parallel-processing, binary, mpi

My goal is to assign a processor to read a binary file into some storage for a matrix, then send it to the processor that matrix is assigned to for calculations. Then afterwards. This program would need to be able to accomodate a variable size of the matrix, and a variable number of processors.

This is all in C

The actual allocation for the matrix, in case im doing it wrong:

```
void alloc_matrix(
                int nrows,
                int ncols,
                size_t element_size,
                void **matrix_storage,
                void ***matrix,
                int *errvalue){
        int i;
        void *ptr_to_row_in_storage;
        void **matrix_row_start;
        const int MSG_TAG =1;
        //1. Allocate array of full matrix
        *matrix_storage = malloc(nrows *ncols * element_size);


        //2. create 2d matrix based on nrows.
        *matrix = malloc(nrows * sizeof(void*));

        //3. put addresses in each row.
        //get address of start of array of pointers to linear storage, which is address of (*matrix)[0]
        matrix_row_start = (void*) &(*matrix[0]);

        ptr_to_row_in_storage = (void*) *matrix_storage;

        //for each matrix pointer, *matrix[i], i = 0... nrows-1,
        //set it to start of the ith row in linear storage

        for(i = 0; i<nrows; i++){
               //matrix_row_start is address of *matrix[i] and ptr_to_row_in_storage is address of start of ith row.
               //changes content of (*matrix)[i] to store the start of the ith row in linear storage.
               *matrix_row_start = (void*) ptr_to_row_in_storage;
                matrix_row_start++;
                ptr_to_row_in_storage += ncols * element_size;
        }
        *errvalue = SUCCESS;
}
```

The code for reading the file into the matrices to be sent:

```
void read_and_distribute_matrix(
                char *filename,
                void ***matrix, //matrix to fill
                void **matrix_storage, //linear storage for matrix
                MPI_Datatype dtype,
                int *nrows, // rows in matrix
                int *ncols, // columns in matrix
                MPI_Comm comm
                ){
...
        if(p-1 == id){
                int nrows_to_send;
                int num_elements;
                size_t nelements_read;
                int i;
                //for process i go up to p-2 and send chunk of bytes to process i from p-1.

                for(int i=0; i< p-1; i++){
                        nrows_to_send = number_of_rows (i, *nrows, p);
                        num_elements = nrows_to_send * (*ncols);

                        nelements_read = fread(*matrix_storage, element_size,
                                num_elements, file);

                        //check number read
                        MPI_Send (*matrix_storage, num_elements, dtype,
                                        i, MSG_TAG, comm);
                }



                nelements_read = fread(*matrix_storage, element_size,
                                nlocal_rows * (*ncols), file);

                fclose(file);
        }
        else{
                MPI_Recv( *matrix_storage, nlocal_rows * (*ncols),
                                dtype, p-1, MSG_TAG, comm, &status);
        }
```

So the last processor would be in charge with reading the file, and sending the read data to the appropriate processor, using MPI_Send. Then the processor, using MPI_Recv, obtains the data and places it in its local matrix_storage. But when I try to print the matrices, I receive this message:

```
*** An error occurred in MPI_Recv
*** reported by process 
*** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
*** MPI_ERR_TAG: invalid tag
*** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
 ***    and potentially your MPI job)
1 more process has sent help message help-mpi-errors.txt / mpi_errors_are_fatal
 Set MCA parameter "orte_base_help_aggregate" to 0 to see all help / error messages
```

As I am still a novice in MPI, and I have identified the error to come from MPI_Send, but not sure how to fix it. I have tried changing the method of allocation to disastrous results, or comparing the matrix differently. Is there an area I should look at?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you define `MSG_TAG` ?

Comment: const int MSG_TAG =1;